# Key - Value store that supports searching by values

Tags: postgresql, redis, key-value

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Api project. For a part of my system I need a key-value store to store strings. Both the key and the value are strings (although they can be long ones). Both keys and values are unique.

Initially, I started using `Redis`, the problem is that I need to search within the store not only by key but also by value (determine if the value exists, no need to return the key in this situation).

Basically, I have two options, the first one is using the default db for my project - `PostgreSQL`. Otherwise I should choose another key-value store which supports the above-mentioned operation. Which option would you suggest? If the second one, which store supports such an operation? Which option is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's you need is NOT another data store, but a value index. Even if you use postgresql or mongodb or something else, you still need to build an index for value to do efficient value search.

For the redis solution, you can use an extra `SET` to store all values. When you want to check the existence of a value, just lookup the `SET`. Of course, whenever you add a new pair of kv, you also need to update the `SET`.

Also, with Lua script, you can make the two updates operations in a transaction.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use Redis, the solution with the set will make it easier.

Comment: Note: searching by value in Redis isn't always trivial, and while Sets can go a long way (and Sorted Sets even further) there are challenges... for an easier and much more robust solution, check out redisearch.io - the fastest search engine in the world built as a Redis module.